# Alternative for DBMS_METADATA.GET_DLL in Oracle 8i

Tags: oracle, oracle8i, database-metadata

In our project we have one database running on oracle 8i (i know this version is ancient but ...)

I want to check the DDL statement for one PUBLIC database link i tried :

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('DB_LINK', 'LINKNAME', 'PUBLIC') from dual;

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('DB_LINK', 'LINKNAME', 'PUBLIC') from dual;
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: invalid column name
```

As per my knowledge it seems like oracle 8i does not support `dbms_metadata`. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Table `dba_db_links` gave me bit information but missing SID of target database.

Is there any way to get DDL statement on Oracle 8i apart from exporting the database/schema ?

Comment: Seriously... *8i*? That's previous century! Upvoting, since I would also like to know what people used to do in 8i days, because as far as I can say, you will get all the details from your **source control**.

Comment: Hopefully your question does not mean "What was the password used for this DB-Link?". The password you will not get in any case.

Comment: @LalitKumarB : Will check for source control. If you have any link regarding this can u please share ?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : Nope , it doesnt mean for password.

Comment: @NagendraNigade Source/version control is maintained by every team. So if you have it, then check for the database source code.

Comment: PS: if you need password for db link then use google. There is some x$_.. view where you will find it in plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the data dictionary:

```
SELECT 'CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK "'||DB_LINK||'" CONNECT TO '||USERNAME||' IDENTIFIED BY "<PWD>" USING '''||HOST||''';' AS cmd
FROM DBA_DB_LINKS
WHERE owner = 'PUBLIC'
    AND DB_LINK = 'LINKNAME';
```

If you miss information try to select table `sys.link$` instead.

Comment: Yeah...i missed the column `host` in `dba_db_links`. Done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use exp/imp tools. Export that database (or schema) using `exp rows=now` and then import it back into the database using `imp show=yes`.

This will not make any changes in the database, but all DDLs will be put into the logfile.

Comment: Yes , This will be very helpful for tables.